# To set SQL as language for .pks and .pkb files in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I am an Oracle Developer. We use Oracle PL/SQL as our programming language. We generally save Package Specification and Package Body as .pks and .pkb format respectively.

When I open the files in Notepad++ , I need to select the language as SQL every time.

Is there any way to default the language as SQL for the above file formats ?

Regards,
Siva

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to 'Settings' > 'Style Configurator'.
2. Select 'SQL' in the 'Language' list on the left.
3. Enter 'pks pkb' in the 'User ext.' box.
4. Click 'Save & Close'.